# unix pipe multiple writers

Tags: unix, ipc, pipe

If there are multiple threads writing fixed length data (say 4 byte address) to a single pipe and there is a single reader of that pipe, is it guaranteed that the reader will get bytes in order? In other words, is `write()` to a pipe atomic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html)

> Atomic/non-atomic: A write is atomic
>   if the whole amount written in one
>   operation is not interleaved with data
>   from any other process. This is useful
>   when there are multiple writers
>   sending data to a single reader.
>   Applications need to know how large a
>   write request can be expected to be
>   performed atomically. This maximum is
>   called {PIPE_BUF}. This volume of IEEE
>   Std 1003.1-2001 does not say whether
>   write requests for more than
>   {PIPE_BUF} bytes are atomic, but
>   requires that writes of {PIPE_BUF} or
>   fewer bytes shall be atomic.

Comment: Thanks. I saw the man page http://linux.die.net/man/2/write and didn't see anything.

Comment: Note that the value of `PIPE_BUF` varies significantly between Unix systems. See here for a collation of observed values: http://ar.to/notes/posix#pipe-buf